# Google Calendar API v3 not saving event location and attendees

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-calendar-api, ktor

I'm testing **Google Calendar API v3** and the only fields missing are `location` and `attendees` uppon getting calendar events. I'm using REST interface (google oauth2 and the user I'm logged in with is the calendar owner) and I can make all the desired CRUD operations, but for some reason, `location` and `attendees` are ignored. If I use the same payload (copied from console output) with [Google API explorer](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) or Postman it works... what am I missing?

Sample playload:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[YOUR_CALENDAR_ID]/events?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "end": {
    "timeZone": "Europe/Lisbon",
    "dateTime": "2021-05-13T10:00:00+01:00"
  },
  "start": {
    "timeZone": "Europe/Lisbon",
    "dateTime": "2021-05-13T08:00:00+01:00"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "batman@mail.com"
    }
  ],
  "location": "Batcave"
}
```

I'm using Ktor, and this is the code:

```
client.post<Event>("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events") {
    body = event
    parameter(API_KEY_PARAMETER, apiKey)
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, token)
}
```

where Event:

```
@Serializable
data class Event(
    val id: String = "",
    val status: String = "",
    val created: String = "",
    val updated: String = "",
    val creator: Attendee,
    val start: DateLabel,
    val end: DateLabel,
    val summary: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
    val location: String = "",
    val attendees: List<Attendee> = emptyList(),
    val maxAttendees: Int = 5
)

@Serializable
data class DateLabel(
    val date: String = "",
    val dateTime: String = "",
    val timeZone: String = ""
)

@Serializable
data class Attendee(val email: String)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the `REST interface` with which you are doing the failing request? Is there any code involved? Are you doing that exact same request? (needless to say it's also working for me via `Try this API`).

Comment: @Iamblichus question updated

Comment: @Iamblichus I've found it, beginner mistake of course, wrong object reference...